# Find style properties of element that I'm creating dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

If I have a CSS style:

```css
.myClass {
    width: 1234px;
}
```

And an element that I add dynamically with JS thus:

```js
document.onload = function(){
    myParent = document.getElementById("parent");
    let myNewElmt = document.createElement("div");
    myNewElmt.className = "myClass";
    myParent.appendChild(MyNewElmt);
    console.log(myNewElmt.style.width);//expect "1234px" returns ""
}
```

I can't access the style properties. It renders fine, and if I subsequently look at `myNewElmt.style.width`, say in a `document.onmousedown` function it works, but not when it's created.

How do I access css styles of a dynamically created element, at the time that it is created?

Comment: You have some typos: `myParent.appendChild(MyNewElmt);` and `myNewElemt.style.width` and here.. should be `myNewElmt`.. does that fix the issue?

Comment: No, the typos were just from the simplified version I created for this question. The problem was what you outlined in your answer, that I was using myNewElmt.style instead of `getComputedStyle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that `element.style.propName` is only used to access the inline style properties that we set using `style` attribute like:

```
<div style="height: 200px;">
```

To access the CSS property value which we set using the class names, we need to use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) for it like:

```
let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(myNewElmt);
console.log( compStyles.width );
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
myParent = document.getElementById("parent");
let myNewElmt = document.createElement("div");

myNewElmt.style.height = '200px';       // Set iniline height here
myNewElmt.className = "myClass";
myParent.appendChild(myNewElmt);

console.log( myNewElmt.style.height );  // Returns 200px
console.log( myNewElmt.style.width );   // Returns ''

let compStyles = window.getComputedStyle(myNewElmt);
console.log( compStyles.width );        // Returns 1234px
```

```css
.myClass { width: 1234px; }
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

**Explanation:**

In this demo, you can see using:

```
console.log( myNewElmt.style.height );
```

we get the correct height as 200px, as we have set the inline height using `myNewElmt.style.height = '200px';`, but `myNewElmt.style.width` returns empty string, as the width is set here using the class and by using `window.getComputedStyle(myNewElmt)` we are able to access the `width` properly.

Comment: I see that I was confusing `style.width` for the computed style. After looking at this I ended up using `getBoundingClientRect()` which did what I wanted, because it included other dynamically modified style changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an attribute to your element

`yourElement.setAttribute("class", "nameClass");`

or `classList()`